# If $f$ is continuous on $(0,5)$, is it uniformly continuous on same interval

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

I have a function, $f$ that is differentiable on $(0,5)$, and I know it is continuous on $(0,5).$  Is it also uniformly continuous on $(0,5)?$  I believe it is.

I now know that it is not. Can someone give me a proof of this please

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. For example, define $f:(0,5)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 1/x$. $f$ is certainly differentiable and continuous on $(0,5)$, but it is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: can I see a proof of that.  I believe you, but since 1/x is continuous, by definition, for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.  In order for uniform continuity, $x,y\in(0,5)$ and $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. So what is wrong here

Comment: The general idea is this. I tell you that I want $\left|f(x)-f(a)\right| < \epsilon$. Can you tell me a $\delta$ so that when $\left|x-y\right| < \delta$,$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right| < \epsilon$, for all $x,y\in(0,5)$?